# How can I make a picture like this with tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to make like this picture with tikz

thanx

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the short compilable tex code you have tried so far ... Do you know the formula for the several curves? Add them to your question!

Answer (score 3):

If you know the formula for your curves, you could use tikz package as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[below] {$r$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[left] {$W$};
\draw[domain=0.2:9.8,blue,samples=300,Green,line width=1pt] plot ({\x},{1/\x})node[left,above]{rep1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the results:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you know the equations it has to be something like this (can't remember the real formulas right now, but it is something like this):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex,thick,black] (0,0)--(5,0);
\draw[-latex,thick,black] (0,-4.5)--(0,4.5);
\draw[domain=0.5:4.5,thick,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{-1/(\x*\x)});
\draw[domain=0.5:4.5,thick,smooth,variable=\x,red] plot ({\x},{0.5/(\x*\x*\x)});
\draw[domain=0.35:4.5,thick,dashed,variable=\x,green!60!black,samples=200] plot ({\x},{-1/(\x*\x))+0.5/(\x*\x*\x)});
\node[red] at (2,1) {attraction};
\node[blue] at (2,-1) {repulsion};
\node[green!60!black,rotate=45] at (0.49,-1.15) {resulted};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very mutch

Comment: Welcome ... happens to be a physicist but can't remember the actual formulas right now ... I think it is something similar... Use the actual formulas please with just the relation of the constants and not the actual numbers (like 13.6 etc)

Comment: I tried to change the parameters of the formula to get the same graph as the photo but I failed.

Comment: @moumou85 The photo you provided is not really mathematically correct ... Mathematically if the distance is zero the repulsion will be infinitive ... I have no the skills on English to search and find the correct formulas but sure they are really close to mine (except of the constants that has to be changed anyway like my example) ... (Just show I have opposite labels)

Comment: Ok thank you  koleygr

Comment: Welcome @moumou85 ...